# How to get the div (green line) on one table row to continue onto the next

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a simple schedule calendar. I'm unable to get the event (green line) in div of one table row to continue on the next row in cases where an event spans multiple days. As seen in the attached picture 
[Calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqVO7.jpg)

Please help. Code: [JS.do](http://js.do/fab/caltest)

Comment: You won't achieve it in the way you hope, you'll have to create a separate green line on the next table row of the relevant length of the event

Comment: This is a horrible way to accomplish this, sorry.

Comment: @RickCalder how would you do it? I'm a newbie can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Use second `<div>` and then you can do whatever you want. For example:

```html
<table>
 <thead>
     <tr>
      <th style="height:10px; width:100px">Monday</th>
            <th style="height:10px; width:100px">Tuesday</th>
            <th style="height:10px; width:100px">Wednesday</th>
            <th style="height:10px; width:100px">Thursday</th>
            <th style="height:10px; width:100px">Friday</th>
            <th style="height:10px; width:100px">Saturday</th>
            <th style="height:10px; width:100px">Sunday</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr>
         <td><div style="height:100px; width:100px; background-color:red; ">1
             <div style="height:10px; width:1000px; background-color:green;"></div>
            </div></td>
            <td><div style="height:100px; width:100px">2</div></td>
            <td><div style="height:100px; width:100px">3</div></td>
            <td><div style="height:100px; width:100px">4</div></td>
            <td><div style="height:100px; width:100px">5</div></td>
            <td><div style="height:100px; width:100px">6</div></td>
            <td><div style="height:100px; width:100px">7</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td><div style="height:100px; width:100px">
                8
                <div style="height:10px; width:1000px; background-color:green;"></div>
                </div></td>
            <td><div style="height:100px; width:100px">9</div></td>
            <td><div style="height:100px; width:100px">10</div></td>
            <td><div style="height:100px; width:100px">11</div></td>
            <td><div style="height:100px; width:100px">12</div></td>
            <td><div style="height:100px; width:100px">13</div></td>
            <td><div style="height:100px; width:100px">14</div></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script></script>
```

Comment: I've edited that. Check now. And, to be honest – you should use classes for that.

Comment: Alexander Paul's answer is with classes. It's not so literally your way, but it's just better ;)

Comment: The div still overflows after 7. Can it continue on the next days till 10?

Comment: Yes, just changing it's ``width``. But really – check Alexander's answer. I was trying to do what you need in the same way as your. Alexander's method is better. It doesn't create bugs (my can).

Comment: Ok. Does Alexander's method work in cases of multiple events per day?

Comment: It'll work if you implement it good – it will do anything what you want. (Mine version can work too, but it's hard to implement)

Answer (score 0):

## Update:

In case of multiple bottom borders for multiple events per day.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9bghpryg/1/)

## Original:

With your approach you can not get what you need. I've changed a bit your code, I hope that's what you need.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k5jeqq30/)

```
<style>
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
    border-bottom: 10px solid white;
    width:100px;
    height:80px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

th {
    height:10px;
    width:100px;
}

.red {
    background-color: red;
}

.event {
    border-bottom-color: green;
}
</style>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Monday</th>
            <th>Tuesday</th>
            <th>Wednesday</th>
            <th>Thursday</th>
            <th>Friday</th>
            <th>Saturday</th>
            <th>Sunday</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="red event">1</td>
            <td class="event">2</td>
            <td class="event">3</td>
            <td class="event">4</td>
            <td class="event">5</td>
            <td class="event">6</td>
            <td class="event">7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="event">8</td>
            <td class="event">9</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>13</td>
            <td>14</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This works for 1 event per day. What if there are multiple events per day?

Comment: In this case you need a new approach. Take a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9bghpryg/1/)

Answer (score -1):

A `<div>` never wraps, it is always rectangular. You have to use two `<div>`s.

Example:

```
<div>Before</div>
<div>
   ... your content here ...
</div>
<div>After</div>
```

Comment: Can you please give an example how to do that?